# About zeros of analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following problem:

Let $\{b_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ a sequence of complex numbers such that $|b_n|<r$ for all $n\geq 1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}|b_n|=r$.

Exists an analytic function $f$ in $|z|<r$ such that $f(b_n)$ is a zero of order $n$?

I think that the answer is no and I know that the zeros of an analytic function are isolated points. But, if is it the right way I don't know how to continue.

What happens in the case that $f$ is meromorphic and $f(b_n)$ is a pole of order $n$?

Any hint or idea will be appreciated !

Comment: To clarify: You are wondering if such situation is possible, or if such function can be built based on arbitrary $b_n$? In other words, would you accept a specific $b_n$ and $f(z)$ as an answer in the positive, or do you specifically need $b_n$ to be arbitrary up to the given conditions?

Comment: @Mefitico sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm asking if such $f$ analytic (meromorphic) exists with the contidions of $\{b_n\}$ given

Comment: Look up [Weierstrass factorization theorem](http://planetmath.org/WeierstrassFactorizationTheorem).